# Spring Boot JPA Repository [SQLITE_BUSY] Error

Tags: java, sqlite, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem while trying to insert **multiple users** on a single button click. Some users are inserted, some are not. For those who are not, I'm receiving Internal Server Error. Actually, SQLite manager is trying to `INSERT User` while DB is locked executing the `SELECT` commands.

> I need a solution for JPA repository to somehow wait, for finishing execution a single `INSERT User` request, and then moving and executing another.

### Request response message

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
```

### SQLite Error

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
```

---

### Insert method (Spring Boot, Java)

```
public User Insert(UserDTO user){

    User userObj = new User();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userObj);

    // SELECT commands
    Optional<Country> country= _countryRepository.findById(user.getCountry_id());
    Optional<Shop> shop = _shopRepository.findById(user.getShop_id());

    if(shop.isEmpty() || country.isEmpty())
        return null;

    userObj.setCountry(country.get() );
    userObj.setShop(shop.get());

    // INSERT command
    return _userRepository.save(userObj);

}
```

Comment: you are not showing how you are implementing this statement `insert multiple users on a single button click`

Comment: This is from client side in Angular, just creating the post request. This is the method:  `postUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(
     "http://localhost:8080/api/user",
      user,
      httpOptions
    );
  }`

Comment: It works perfectly on a single request, but when I'm calling this method in **foreach loop**, the problem occurs.

Comment: I propose that you avoid looping like this and extend your API to accept a list of users to create

Comment: Could be a solution, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @Adnan did @Ahmed HENTETI's solution work for you? I had a similar issue in a spring boot application. The solution for me was to set the maximum hikari connection pool to 1 in application.properties file. Like this: `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1`